# How Can I change pgbouncer pooling Point? Please help

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

Good morning, 
I have more important questions that PGbouncer in postgreSQL module.

I saw lot of many threads, but I can't solved it.
so, I'm crave answer my question.

The questions are: I am using pgbouncer module on postgreSQL server, Pooling of pgbouncer Pooling starts when the server is running out of resources.

Can I arbitrarily adjust the point of pooling?

I hope that the pooling of pgbouncer will start when the lightweight resources are consumed.

thanks.

( I using transfer{google} ) sorry.